# Powershell: Get-Process Returns "Invalid" VM Size

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm running PowerShell 2.0 on Windows XP SP3 and I execute:

```
PS> ps firefox
```

And it returns:

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
    859      44   340972     351580   684 9,088.22   7744 firefox
```

However, Windows Task Manager shows the following stats for firefox.exe:

```
Mem Usage: 354,720 K
VM Size:   347,322 K
```

Why is the VM output from PowerShell 300 MB more than that output from Windows Task Manager?

**EDIT:**
It looks like the `PM` (`PagedMemorySize`) property output from PowerShell is lining up closely to the "VM Size" output from Windows Task Manager.  However,  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.pagedmemorysize.aspx) says the `PagedMemorySize` property is obsolete.  Should I rely on the `PM` property to get the virtual memory?  What does the `VM` property represent?

Answer (score 1):

[This post](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/What-do-the-Task-Manager-memory-columns-mean) might help explain what the various memory columns in task manager correspond to. I've noticed some discrepancies when compared with Process Explorer too.